# why one application pool has 4 worker processes in IIS

Tags: 2010, iis, performancepoint, application-pool, worker-process

why one application pool has 4 worker processes in IIS

this application pool for Performancepoint service running in sharepoint application server
[image]

Answer (score 1):

An application pool that contains multiple worker processes is called a **Web Garden**.

Now, I am not sure if those 4 worker processes were set up during the installation of PerformancePoint or if someone else set them up after the installation. Either way, a web garden is good because:

- Provides better application availability by sharing requests between multiple worker process.
- Web garden uses processor affinity where application can be swapped out based on preference and tag setting.
- Less consumption of physical space for web garden configuration.

Reference: [What is the difference between Web Farm and Web Garden?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114910/What-is-the-difference-between-Web-Farm-and-Web-Ga)